# como puedo crear esta consulta de mysql en doctrine es posible?

Tags: mysql, symfony3, doctrine2

tengo esta consulta que hice en mysql

```
SELECT 'formulario' as formulario, 'persona' as persona, 'uds' as uds, GROUP_CONCAT(pg.enunciado SEPARATOR ';') as valores_respuestas 
    FROM preguntas_de_formularios as pdf 
    INNER JOIN preguntas as pg on pg.id_pregunta = pdf.pregunta WHERE pdf.formulario = 5 
UNION
SELECT q.nombre as formulario, q.nombres as persona , q.nombre_uds as uds, GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(q.valor_respuesta, 0 ) SEPARATOR ';') as valores_respuestas
 from (
   SELECT f.nombre, pf.posicion, pr.id_pregunta, r.id_respuesta , df.respuesta, p.id_persona,CONCAT(p.nombres, ' ', p.apellidos ) as nombres, u.nombre_uds, pr.enunciado as pregunta, 
    IF(da.valor IS NOT NULL, da.valor, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(o.enunciado, IF(df.otro IS NULL,'', CONCAT(': ',df.otro))) SEPARATOR '\n\n')) as valor_respuesta
   from 
    preguntas_de_formularios as pf
    inner join preguntas as pr on pr.id_pregunta = pf.pregunta
    LEFT join formularios as f on f.id_formulario = pf.formulario
    inner join soluciones as s on s.formulario = f.id_formulario 
    LEFT join persona as p on p.id_persona = s.persona
    LEFT join uds as u on u.id_uds = s.uds
    LEFT join respuestas as r on r.solucion = s.id_solucion and r.pregunta = pf.pregunta and (r.categoria = pf.categoria  OR (r.categoria IS NULL and pf.categoria IS NULL))
    LEFT join detalle_respuesta_fija as df on  df.respuesta = r.id_respuesta
    LEFT join opciones as o on o.id_opcion = df.opcion
    LEFT join detalle_respuesta_abierta as da on da.respuesta = r.id_respuesta
    where f.id_formulario = 5
    group by  df.respuesta, pr.id_pregunta, p.id_persona
    order by nombres, pf.posicion, r.id_respuesta) as q
  group by q.id_persona
```

Quisiera crearla en doctrine, es posible con los group concat y todo o debo crearla con

```
$this->em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
```

Comment: por lo que tengo entendido Doctrine no soporta actualmente la clausula UNION, por lo que en tu caso no veo mas remedio que utilizar la solución que te brinda Juan, utilizando la conexion del manager y el prepare($sql). Revida su solucion

Answer (score 2):

Dependiendo de donde estés realizando la consulta; suponiendo que estés en el archivo repository, la sintaxis sería la siguiente:

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$sql = '//Tu query';


$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

> //$stmt->bindValue('expresion',$valor) se debe utilizar esta funcion para bindeo de valores externos

```
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->fetchAll();  //Retorna el resultado
```